# How to use FlySystem for storage in a NextCloud app?

Tags: php, nextcloud, flysystem

I am developing an app for Nextcloud that needs to read and write files. Part of my code is provided by a library that uses FlySystem. In the NextCloud codebase there is a FlySystem class:

https://github.com/nextcloud/server/blob/master/lib/private/Files/Storage/Flysystem.php

The code says it is a

> Generic adapter between flysystem adapters and owncloud’s storage system

That sounds *exactly* like what I need!

But how do I use that class provided by the Nextcloud codebase? I couldn't really find any documentation about that...

Comment: Have you visited this [link](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v1/docs/) ?

Comment: Yes. I know how Flysystem works... What I am not familiar with is NextCloud, how its storage works and how FlySystem ties into it all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, there wasn't any Flysystem adapter to use the FlySystem API within Nextcloud.

The existing class in `/lib/private/Files/Storage/Flysystem.php` is meant/used to allow Nextcloud to talk to an external storage location.

In the end, we created our own Adapter to allow working *within* Nextcloud using the Flysystem API: [`pdsinterop/flysystem-nextcloud`](https://github.com/pdsinterop/flysystem-nextcloud)

[image]